# Remove everything in a string inbetween two characters

Tags: c#

I have a bit of data I'm extracting from a webpage, and I want to know how I can remove everything between these characters- < and >, while also removing those characters themselves.  Here is an example of a string I am getting from a site-

```
<a>SomeTextHere</a>Moretext<br><tr>SomeText</tr>
```

I want to have my final result to be-

```
SomeTextHere MoreText SomeText
```

Is there a way I can do this quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Just some addition to the answer from @codebased below: `.*?`  is a regular expression and stands for "everything". <EVERYTHING> will be replaced with `string.Empty` (stands for ""). If you want a whitespace you need to replace `string.Empty` with `" "`. You can find regex in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're asking for is to replace multiple contiguous html tags with a single space, while codebased's answer would just concatenate what was on either side of the tag

The following will strip actual tags and html comments while preserving everything else (including < and > characters that don't form part of a tag declaration.

```
private string StripTagsRegex(string source) 
{
    return Regex.Replace(source, "(</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--.*?-->)+", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
}
```

Using this method:

`<a>SomeTextHere</a>Moretext<br><tr>SomeText</tr>`

becomes

`SomeTextHere MoreText SomeText`

which is what I think you were really asking for.

Comment: This seems to be formatted better, vs codebased's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple RegEx.

```
private string StripTagsRegex(string source) 
{
            return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

For more complex work, use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net), a tool commonly recommended for this. It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM like the XML classes.

Comment: Though I would like to say that I did attempt to work with the htmlagilitypack, and it would not return reliable results.